# C - How to get the string of the outer token in a nested strtok_s

Tags: c

text block:

```
00000001,otherPerson,0134333334,anotherDepartment
00000002,anotherPerson,01287665478,newDepartment
00000003,someoneElse,0139487632,otherDepartment
00000004,wholeNewPerson,01786666317,aDeparment
00000005,aPerson,013293842,otherDepartment
00000006,oldPerson,0133937333,anotherDepartment
```

I am trying to process a block of text data by checking if a column in a row is equal to a value and then get the complete row.
I split the block of text into rows by `\n` and then split the row into column by `,`. But in the inner iteration of the text splitting, the outer token is no more complete row. How to keep the token complete?

```
char *sav1 = NULL;
char *token = strtok_s(copyOfRecords, "\n", &sav1);
int counter = 0;

while (token != NULL) {
    char *sav2 = NULL;
    char *innerToken = strtok_s(token, ",", &sav2);
    int counter = 1;

    while (innerToken != NULL) {
        // the variable, "token" is not complete anymore in this block
        // How to keep the outer token complete?

        innerToken = strtok_s(NULL, ",", &sav2);
    }

    token = strtok_s(NULL, "\n", &sav1);
}
```

Comment: What `strtok_s()` implementation is that?  That's not the [C standard `strtok_s()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.7.3.1) implementation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's a Microsoft extension.

Comment: @dbush So it's another example of a Microsoft extension that is inconsistent with the C standard?  Let me guess:  if you try to use C standard `strtok()`, Microsoft's compiler "helpfully" lies to you about `strtok()` being deprecated...

Comment: @AndrewHenle: yes, you get a deprecation warning. Another example of their famous [EEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish) strategy.

Comment: I make it a point to define `_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS` and `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to silence those warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strtok` family of functions modify the string they seem to extract tokens from. This is confusing and often counter-productive as you experience.

Further confusion comes from the semantics of this tokenisation process, also often misunderstood: for example `strtok(token, ",")` will interpret any number of consecutive commas as a single separator, which means it cannot handle empty comma separated fields. `strtok_s()`, which is a Microsoft extension not always available on non Microsoft systems, behaves the same way. Consider not using these functions at all.

You should instead use `strcspn()` to skip lines and columns and reach your target cell, test its size and contents and return a pointer to the row if there is a match or `NULL` if there is no match. This way you can restart a search from the last match.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *select_row(const char *data, int col, const char *value) {
    size_t value_len = strlen(value);
    while (*data != '\0') {
        const char *p = data;
        size_t row_len = strcspn(p, "\n"); // count the number of characters different than newline
        size_t data_len;
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
            p += strcspn(p, ",\n");  // skip the cell contents
            if (*p == ',') {
                p++;  // skip the comma to point to the next cell
            }
        }
        // p points to the column data
        size_t cell_len = strcspn(p, ",\n");  // compute the cell contents' length
        if (cell_len == len && memcmp(p, value, len) == 0) {
            // if there is a match, return a pointer to the beginning of the row.
            // beware that this is not a token as the data was not modified so
            // the row data stops at the newline but the string goes to the end of
            // the database.
            // you can return an allocated copy of the row with
            // return strndup(data, data_len);
            return (char *)data;
        }
        data += data_len;  // skip the row contents
        if (*data == '\n') {
            data++;   // skip the newline to point to the next row.
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    const char *data = "00000001,otherPerson,0134333334,anotherDepartment\n"
                       "00000002,anotherPerson,01287665478,newDepartment\n"
                       "00000003,someoneElse,0139487632,otherDepartment\n"
                       "00000004,wholeNewPerson,01786666317,aDeparment\n"
                       "00000005,aPerson,013293842,otherDepartment\n"
                       "00000006,oldPerson,0133937333,anotherDepartment\n";

    const char *found = select_row(data, 1, "anotherPerson");
    int length = strcspn(found, "\n");
    if (found) {
        printf("%.*s\n", length, data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is this still going to work if passing a single char* as the text block?

Comment: @CloudWave: yes it does and it does not modify the text block so you can use it repeatedly for different cells. It is an inefficient way to handle a database in memory, but for a small one, it works fine.

Comment: C programming is making me feel frustrated.. I am having difficulty to understand your algorithm

Comment: @CloudWave: I added comments for you to follow the steps. `strcspn()` and `strspn()` are standard string functions that are often overlooked but very useful for parsing data. Study how they work from the man page or a tutorial.

Comment: what is the use of the parameters row and col?

Comment: I thought you wanted to check a given cell contents. But instead you want to look up a row where a given column matches a string. Answer updated

Comment: Could you show me how would you call the function with parameters?

Comment: @CloudWave: I added a `main()` function with an example.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to handle this is to make a copy of the outer token.

```
while (token != NULL) {
    char *token_orig = _strdup(token);
    char *innerToken = strtok_s(token, ",", &sav2);
    int counter = 1;

    while (innerToken != NULL) {
        // Use token_orig

        innerToken = strtok_s(NULL, ",", &sav2);
    }

    token = strtok_s(NULL, "\n", &sav1);
    free(token_orig);
}
```

Comment: I tried copy the token with malloc and strcpy, but the token has been split at this moment of the iteration so the copied value is the first piece of the split

Comment: @CloudWave If you do the copy as soon as you enter the loop, before calling `strtok_s` on `token`, you should get the whole thing.

Comment: You might as well duplicate the original data as well to avoid trashing it with `strtok_s()`.

Comment: This works given that the splitting is implemented on a copy of the text block